# comparing two numbers if it follows the sequence in an array

Tags: php, loops, logic

I'm not quite sure how to do it but this is the scenario.

I have an array of strings which follows a specific order.

```
$array = ['A','B','C','D','E'];
```

and I have two inputs that takes strings, what I want to do is to check if the two input strings are in sequence based on the array given.

for Example

```
$array = ['A','B','C','D','E'];
$input1 = 'B';
$input2 = 'D';

//this should return true
```

However if this is the case

```
 $array = ['A','B','C','D','E'];
 $input1 = 'D';
 $input2 = 'A';

 //this should return false
```

`$input1` should always comes first before the `$input2`

I've tried several ways using looping to do it but I cannot get the desired result.

appreciate any help. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems a simple loop would suffice if you track whether or not you've seen the first value.

```
function my_function_name($array, $input1, $input2){
    $found_input_one = FALSE;
    foreach($array as $a){
        if($a == $input1){
            $found_input_one = TRUE;
        }
        if($a == $input2 && $found_input_one){
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find an index of both inputs with `array_search()`

In order the two inputs are in sequence, the index of the first input must be lower than the index of the second input. Also `array_search()` returns `false` if not found.

```
function inSequence($array, $input1, $input2) {
    $index1 = array_search($input1, $array);
    $index2 = array_search($input2, $array);

    if($index1 === false || $index2 === false) return false;

    return $index1 < $index2;
}
```